# Skrollr content flashes on and disappears on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, skrollr

I've recently built a website using skrollr which behaves as expected on desktop but not at all on iOS.

On iOS, the website will begin to load, showing some content and then change to a blank white page, with only the menu still showing on top.

The only way I've managed to get it to start working on iOS again has been to start deleting sections. I thought maybe I'd work out the problem section through a process of elimination but it turns out that it doesn't matter *which* sections I delete, as long as I delete *some*.

I've used skrollr on a few different projects and haven't seen this occurring elsewhere and it's left me stumped despite my digging.

[Here is the website](http://eurocity.be). If anyone has any insight, it'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. Using the debugger I can see the elements (their bounding box) when I hover over them, but they're not visible. Also I can see that scrolling works, the #skrollr-body is transformed. But everything is blank. Does it work if you remove the skrollr.init call?

Comment: When removing skrollr.init, the page render but remains unscrollable (because of the height: 100% and overflow:hidden). What debugger are you using? I've had a tough time finding anything useful for iOS making this difficult for me to debug myself

Comment: You can set up weinre to remotely inspect your page http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html